# What is the correct ability score adjustment for the Were-tiger template?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ability-scores, lycanthropy

I have a character who uses the [were-tiger template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/lycanthrope/weretiger/) but I'm slightly confused at the example on the [pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/)

The actual were template says

> Ability Scores: **+2 Wis, –2 Cha in all forms; +2 Str, +2 Con in hybrid and animal forms.** Lycanthropes have enhanced senses but are not fully in control of their emotions and animalistic urges...

But in the example were-tiger they give the human form's STR stat is 13, but the hybrid form's STR is 23. Was this a typo or is the were-tiger template different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the entire section on ability scores. Literally immediately after the line you quote is

> **In addition to these adjustments to the base creature’s stats, a lycanthrope’s ability scores change when he assumes hybrid or animal form.** In human form, the lycanthrope’s ability scores are unchanged from the base creature’s form. In animal and hybrid form, the lycanthrope’s ability scores are the **same as the base creature’s or the base animal’s**, whichever ability score is higher.

So in hybrid or animal form, the weretiger has the Strength score of a [tiger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/cat-great/tiger/), which is indeed 23.

Comment: Oh freaking hell *Facepalm* I even read that part but for some reason it didn't click.

Comment: but would it not gain the +2 to the str as well? so it would be 25 would it not?

Comment: @Ozuma No, "these adjustments" are "to the base creature's stats," not to the stats of any of the other forms.

Comment: hmm okay i just saw the "in hybrid or animal from" bit and thought i should ask